# How to get SPL token value in SOL / USD (exchange rate) using the Raydium SDK?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, spl, raydium

I've already got the SPL token mint address using @solana/spl-token and @solana/web3.js, now I want to get how much this SPL token is valued in SOL using the Raydium SDK.
I've looked at some answers but the solutions are pretty complicated for someone who's pretty new to Raydium SDK and Solana terminology in general.
Would be appreciated if someone could explain more simply and beginner-friendly.
Thanks a lot.